# File getting copied to SysWOW64 instead of System32 while installing INF thru Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installation, system32, syswow64

We have INF file which installs one .sys file to windows drivers folder. Scenario is as follows:

1) Installing the INF from File Explorer. Right click on INF file and click on Install. In this scenario .sys file gets copy under Windows\System32\drivers folder.

2) Created console application to install using RunDll32 / CMD under process object and install the INF file. In this scenario .sys file gets copy under Windows\System32\drivers folder.

3) Created x86 installer program having installer class to install using RunDll32 / CMD under process object and install the INF file. In this scenario .sys file gets copy under Windows\SysWOW64\drivers.

Our objective is to copy .sys file under Windows\System32\drivers folder irrespective of 32/64 bit flavor windows operating systems like WinXP, Windows7, Windiows 8/8.1/10.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer (MSI) installs insist on installing 32-bit components in an x86 setup to the 32-bit locations. Attempts to direct 32-bit files to 64-bit locations will result in redirection. A 64-bit install can install to both.

Different MSIs are required for different architectures:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/

and see in particular the WIN64DUALFOLDERS log and the accompanying remarks.